# Application force close when i access delete method database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

my application force closes when i access delete method, it works fine with insert and get items method.
in databasehandler,

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
private static final String _id = "_id";
private static final String name = "name";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTableQuery = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _id
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + name + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTableQuery);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}

public void insertData(String label) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(name, label);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void deleteData(String item){
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.delete(TABLE_NAME, name+ "='" +item +"'", null);
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE name='"+item+"'");
    db.close();
}

     public Set<String> getAllData() {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    String selectQuery = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            set.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return set;
}
   }
```

and in my activity, i have this and

```
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
     long id) {
    String deleteitem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    db.deleteData(deleteitem);
    loadSpinner();
    }
```

if i remove " db.deleteData(deleteitem); " from my activity, it works without any issues. i don't know where i am wrong. everything seems to be fine.

```
 05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TABLE_NAME: DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE name='Hi i am not available now. i will contact you soon.'
 05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at com.praveenkutti1990.ezmesseger.DatabaseHandler.deleteData(DatabaseHandler.java:50)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at com.praveenkutti1990.ezmesseger.ListActivity.onItemSelected(ListActivity.java:90)
 05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  05-17 16:44:01.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1936):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  05-17 16:44:03.945: I/Process(1936): Sending signal. PID: 1936 SIG: 9
```

my activity

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
         OnItemSelectedListener {

private EditText edittext;
private Button btnAdd;
DatabaseHandler db;
private Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
List<String> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    db = new DatabaseHandler(ListActivity.this);
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    loadSpinner();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name = edittext.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        edittext.setError("Enter a valid Message");
        edittext.requestFocus();
    } else {
        db.insertData(name);
        edittext.setText("");

        // Hiding the keyboard
        InputMethodManager inputmangager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputmangager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Template added Successfully", 0).show();
    Intent in = new Intent(ListActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
     long id) {
    String deleteitem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    //db.deleteData(deleteitem);
    loadSpinner();
    }

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void loadSpinner() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Set<String> set = db.getAllData();

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setWillNotDraw(false);

}

  }
```

Comment: add your logcat output

Comment: check with rawQuery i.e db.rawQuery("delete from table_name where KEY_NAME="+name);

Comment: how many items do you have in spinner? maybe there is something wrong with you loadSpinner() method if you try to load and there is nothing to load, because You deleted the only existing table?

Comment: LOGCAT is your best friend...........

Comment: the error shown in your logcat is class cast exception, show your activity code and check line no 39

Comment: added logcat. i am a newbi  help me with.

Comment: @Rob please show your `ListActivity` code, and mention line number 39 in that

Comment: Problem is in line number 39..

Comment: is R.id.btnadd a button?? or something else??

Comment: Put your xml layout, it's maybe the problem of the Cast Exception

Comment: yeah , i had some other issues too like(cast exception). i cleared it. and struck with the same database delete now. i updated the new logcat please check it

Comment: Have you modified deleteData ? if yes, update it... It's maybe a wrong query again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, name+ "=" +item, null);
```

this line to

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, name+ "=?", new String[] { (item) });
```

like this or else

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, name+ "='" +item+"'", null);
```

like this.

I think you didn't use `btnAdd` anywere in your application. If yes please remove

```
btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
```

this line. And remove comment symbol (`//`) from

```
//db.deleteData(deleteitem);
```

this line.

and also change

```
String createTableQuery = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _id
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + name + " TEXT)";
```

this line to

```
String createTableQuery = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _id
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + name + " TEXT)";
```

like this. note the space between `TABLE_NAME` and `(`.

And let me know what happens.

Comment: i tried everything you mentioned. still can't solve it. button problem has been taken off. please check the logcat i updated now.

Comment: can you post your table creation method also?

Comment: now if i remove // from         //db.deleteData(deleteitem);             it is showing force close otherwise fine.

Comment: i have added my databasehandler.

Comment: its working. this line is working.                      db.delete(TABLE_NAME, name+ "=?", new String[] { (item) });                 thanks Dhanaseelan.

Answer (score 0):

Just ' missing around string like this :

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, name+ "='" +item + "'", null);
```

You are deleting a string in SQL you need to put ' around it.

UPDATE :

Just change this :

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE name='"+item+"'");
```

by :

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " +  TABLE_NAME + " WHERE name='"+item+"'");
```

Comment: thanks, your method is perfect. mine was showing error because the string value has punctuation's in it. somehow it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer execSQL:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM x WHERE y='"+z+"'");
```